# What proportion of a flight do planes spend in the upper atmosphere?

Tags: carbon-footprint

While creating a methodology for the carbon footprint of flights, I came across some information which required the calculation of the distance travelled by a flight in the upper atmosphere. Essentially, aircraft emissions at higher altitudes have a larger climate impact than ones at lower altitudes and to compensate for that, we multiply the emissions when the aircraft is in the upper atmosphere by a constant like 5.2.

> It is recommended to apply the factor if possible only on the emissions in the higher atmosphere
> because this allows for a better differentiation between short and long-distance flights

I have almost no knowledge about aviation and so it was hard for me to gather any information for how I could go about calculating the distance travelled in the upper atmosphere (and then calculate emissions based on the fuel consumption for that distance). I came across a diagram that showed the stages of flight and I guessed that I was attempting to find the proportion of the flight in cruise mode.

[image]

After going through [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66748/does-the-enroute-phase-begin-at-a-30nm-distance-from-the-departure-airport) question on the aviation stack exchange, I figured a good estimate for the distance spent in the en route stage is the total distance travelled minus 60 NM, but I'm not sure if looking at the en route stage is what I want.

[image]

Could someone help me understand a way I could calculate the proportion of a flight that that the aircraft travels in the upper atmosphere? So far I'm expecting to multiply the total distance travelled by a given proportion, say 70%, given that the flight is long enough. Even if such a simple proportion isn't available, is there a way I could potentially calculate it given the origin and destination of a flight (and access to no financial resources for paid databases)?

**Note:** I was unaware that the 'upper atmosphere' had no standard meaning, so for this question defining it as above the troposphere is probably what I want as suggested by [@Ben](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/3746/ben). This also restricts the question to commercial jets as pointed out by [@jamesqf](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/6968/jamesqf)

Comment: I think I have to ask the obvious question, if you have almost no knowledge of aviation, are you the best person to be creating this methodology?  There are many secondary questions such as what do you mean by upper atmosphere, what pollutants are you interested in studying and so on.

Comment: How do you want to define "upper atmosphere"? Because aircraft tend to cruise near the boundary of the troposphere and the stratosphere, which are the two lowest levels of the atmosphere. No aircraft reaches the ionosphere/mesosphere which I would consider to be the upper atmosphere (but I'm sure some boffins have made their own definition for what counts as upper to suit their study goals)

Comment: A jet airliner cruising at something like 35,000’ does NOT start descending at 30nm. An old rule of thumb is 3 times your altitude, so 35,000’ x 3 = 105nm (3 nautical miles per 1000 feet )

Comment: @Ben: "aircraft tend to cruise near the boundary of the troposphere and the stratosphere"?  That's roughly 25K-50K feet (9-17 km).  Most of us probably don't often get above 14K ft or so (and the only times I've been higher have been in sailplanes).  Question needs to be limited to commercial jets & military aircraft.

Comment: @Frog I'm definitely not the best person to be creating this, but it's for a kind of extended school project and I wanted to explore the field as much as I could. I thought about the sort of ambiguous definition of 'upper atmosphere' but I didn't include that in the question to retain focus and thought that maybe the aviation industry has some way of defining it.

Comment: @Ben I think defining 'upper atmosphere' as the lower stratosphere might be what I need. The paper singled that out when talking about the multiplier.

Comment: @jamesqf I'll add the limitation to commercial jets in question, along with some of the other suggestions in this comment thread so far.

Comment: You're asking for a way to "calculate the proportion of a flight [that] the aircraft travels in the upper atmosphere". This assumes that it's a more-or-less fixed proportion, applicable as a blanket solution to all flights. But there's huge variety. A heavy A340 from busy NY to Hong Kong will not be the same as a small CRJ-200LR from a regional airport to another. And let's not even consider diversion due to weather, emergencies, and all that. You can perhaps extrapolate using a **vast** number of flights, but I wouldn't know how to advise you about that in terms of statistical errors etc.

Comment: @DigitalDracula I definitely agree with the fact that a simple proportion like that wouldn't be a very accurate model. If we consider an 'optimal' flight (it travels in a straight line, a simple ascent, cruise, descent, etc.) by a commercial aircraft, do you think approximating the cruise height of the aircraft (maybe making this aircraft-specific), finding the distance required for the ascent & descent (finding aircraft-specific ascent & descent rates) and thus the cruise distance might work to some extent?

Comment: do you think this is an approach worth trying? or is there too much variability in which a model like this might not even work for an average case? In which case, am I better off just not considering the multiplier factor for just the stratosphere?

Comment: I applaud your enthusiasm, and your motivation is noble, but I think this is just too complex to deal with, considering the resources at your disposal. I suppose you could work considering an "optimal flight", but I have no knowledge on how far off reality you would be.

Comment: @DigitalDracula In either case, thanks for your help, it really was quite useful :) I suppose I'll move on to other tasks regarding the calculator then.

Comment: I would challenge the multiplier.  Aircraft create vastly more emissions during the climb than during cruise.

Comment: The aviation part is relatively easy. But you have to *justify* the effects you ascribe to the carbon dioxide released at different levels, and that in turn requires diving deep into physics of atmosphere.

Comment: @MichaelHall Here's the source for the multiplier if you're interested: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327551417_Aviation_and_Climate_Change_Best_practice_for_calculation_of_the_global_warming_potential. I believe that this multiplier has to do with the chemical and physical reactions that take place at that altitude and less with the amount of emissions. The multiplier is multiplied with the emissions at that level (which may be lower than the ascent).

Comment: The total emissions are calculated using the fuel consumption database, given by the ICAO in Appendix C: https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/CarbonOffset/Documents/Methodology%20ICAO%20Carbon%20Calculator_v11-2018.pdf. I believe this adjusts for the larger emissions during ascent since the slope of fuel consumption for lower distance flights is larger than ones for longer flights.

Comment: The question is clear: do we on the Aviation site know what is defined as the Upper Atmosphere, referenced in an article on pollution. Voted to keep open.

Answer (score 1):

From an unverified source, a typical rate of climb is 1800ft/min and the stratosphere is reckoned to begin at 33000ft.  If we assume that the flight begins at sea level and that the descent is also at 1800ft/min then the aircraft will be below the stratosphere for 36 minutes and 40 seconds, and the remainder of the flight will be in the stratosphere.  You would then need to estimate the average duration of a flight, and consider short hops where the maximum altitude may be lower.  Perhaps look at flightradar24.com, grab a snapshot of what’s happening at one instant and assume that it’s representative of typical conditions.  If there’s too much data to look at then select a random subset and analyse them.  There are several assumptions here, so be sure to consider how valid they are and adjust your methods accordingly.

Comment: International Standard Atmosphere has tropopause at 11 km, that is 36,000 ft, not 33,000. But actual height of tropopause varies wildly—from 9 km (30,000 ft) to 17 km (56,000 ft). Since airliners fly mostly between 32,000 ft and 40,000 ft, this variation *cannot be neglected*.

Comment: This may work since we also have a database of the altitudes of all airports, it could help make our calculations more accurate. Do you know how we could calculate the ascent and descent in distance (ie using the groundspeed during the climb) rather than time? We could then subtract that distance from the total flight distance rather than estimating time.

Comment: @JanHudec although that's a pretty valid concern, I don't think it's worth investing too much into or trying to take it into account because the number of variables involved are too many. Unfortunately, I think just assuming that the 'upper atmosphere' is the cruise height of the aircraft (whatever that may be given that it's around 33/36,000 feet), might be the most we can do.

Comment: @BhavyeMathur if that's most you think you can do, then you can just suck some numbers out of your finger and it will be just as good. But if you want your results to have some actual relevance, you absolutely have to understand why you give carbon dioxide released at different altitudes the different signifcance you do.